# An easy way to draw this picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, asymptote

I'm using tikz and would like to obtain this picture:

[image]

My try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,snakes,fit,shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,decorations.markings,positioning,shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {cuboid} node[left]{\simeq} (1,0,0)
    \simeq \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) circle (1);
    \draw[dashed] (-1,0,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.6);
    \draw[dashed] (1,0,0) arc (0:180:1 and 0.6);
    \caption{Sample}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for all, sincerely.

Comment: Please extend your example to a full but minimal document. Adding your code to a naïve doc does not compile

Comment: Done! Not much more that I can add, I think. Thanks!

Comment: Please always check your code. It does not compile without errors. Don't just ignore errors (especially on overleaf). Instead of looking for the 'easiest' way, you should probably learn to draw this ad hoc. Then one can learn more "clever" solutions later.

Comment: @LH8: Can you update the title of your question to be more representative? Describe "this" in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one just done ad hoc.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt 3pt 3pt 3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \def\Erad{2}
  \def\Eang{20}
  \def\Econ{1}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (0:\Erad);
  \coordinate (B) at (180:\Erad);

  \draw (O) circle (\Erad);
  \draw (B) .. controls ++(-\Eang:\Econ) and ++(180+\Eang:\Econ) .. (A);
  \draw[dashed] (B) .. controls ++(\Eang:\Econ) and ++(180-\Eang:\Econ) .. (A);

  \coordinate (T1) at ($(O)+(3.5,-1.5)$);
  \coordinate (T2) at ($(T1)+(2,0)$);
  \coordinate (T3) at ($(T1)+(0,2)$);
  \coordinate (T4) at ($(T1)+(2,2)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(A)!0.5!(A -| T1)$);

%  \fill[red] (C) circle (2pt);
  
  \def\Cang{35}
  \def\Clen{1.3}

  \coordinate (T11) at ($(T1)+(\Cang:\Clen)$);
  \coordinate (T12) at ($(T2)+(\Cang:\Clen)$);
  \coordinate (T13) at ($(T3)+(\Cang:\Clen)$);
  \coordinate (T14) at ($(T4)+(\Cang:\Clen)$);

  \draw[dashed] (T1) -- (T11) -- (T12);
  \draw[dashed] (T11) -- (T13);
  \draw (T4) -- (T14) -- (T13) -- (T3)
  -- (T1) -- (T2) -- (T12) -- (T14)
  (T3) -- (T4) -- (T2)
  ;

  \node at (C) {$\simeq$};
   
  % \fill (T1) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T2) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T3) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T4) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T11) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T12) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T13) circle (2pt);
  % \fill (T14) circle (2pt);

  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, daleif!

Comment: But how you can get an smaller sphere (same size of the cube)? Please

Comment: Read the code and note that the settings used are adjustable

Answer (score 3):

Another try, using the 3d library for the cube:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.3);
    \draw[dashed] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and 0.3);
    
    \node[font=\huge] at (1.7,0) {$\simeq$};

    \begin{scope}[shift={(3,-0.4)}, scale=1.5]
        \draw[dashed] (0,1,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
        \draw (1,0,1) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
        \draw (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (0,1,1);
        \draw (1,1,0) -- (1,1,1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: sphere_sim_cube_with_caption]

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to add a \caption* but it doesn't appear in the center. Do you know a command?

Comment: I edited my answer to also feature a caption. You need to wrap the tikzpicture into a figure environment for the `\caption{}` command to make sense. If you actually wish to use `\caption*{}`, you need to load the `caption` package (or whatever it is where you picked up the command from).

Answer (score 2):

I think TikZ is enough for this figure (the sphere and the cube are homeomorphic).

Here is an Asymptote solution for fun.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(8cm);
usepackage("amssymb");
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(4,1,-1,zoom=.8);
pen p=yellow+opacity(.5);
pen q=red;
triple A=1.5Y;

draw(shift(-A)*unitsphere,p);
draw(shift(-A)*unitcircle3,q);

draw(shift(A-(1,1,1))*scale3(2)*unitcube,p);
draw(shift(A-(1,1,0))*scale3(2)*unitsquare3,q);

label("$\simeq$",O);
```